# How to unit test without unit testing private methods?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

I have quite a bit of code in a method that broadly looks like this

```
public void A(boolean f1, boolean f2, boolean f3, int var1, int var2, String var3) {
    if(f1){
        doSomething(var1)
    } else if(f2) {
        doSomethingElse(var1);
        doSomethingMore(var3);
    } else if(f3) {
        doSomethingDifferent();
        doSomethingElse(var2);
        doSomethingDifferentAgain();
    }
}

private void doSomething(int var) { ... }
private void doSomethingElse(int var) { ... }
private void doSomethingMore(String var) { ... }
private void doSomethingDifferent() { ... }
private void doSomethingDifferentAgain() { ... }
```

Now, if I have these methods all defined as private, how should I be testing them? The logic in each of the methods is fairly self enclosed, but testing just the public method will need a lot more "handling" in the test that a test for just the method.

What is the recommended way to test code like this?

Comment: Recommended way is testing only public methods. If testing public method become **very very complicated** - consider to extract some logic into dedicated class and test it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Parnas 1971](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/)

> What is the recommended way to test code like this?

The basic theme of TDD is that we don't test code like this.  Instead, we replace a design like this one with a design that places a higher priority on testability.

The claim is that, when you prioritize testability, you get the sorts of modules that Parnas was talking about; as a consequence, future changes become much easier to integrate safely into your code base, and therefore you are able to deliver business value at a steady pace.

For a TDD practitioner, complicated tests -- especially tests that are complicated to set up ("Given ...") -- are a symptom.  Often the cause is that there is too much coupling between the thing that we want to measure and other irrelevant details.  The response is to redesign the code so to reduce the coupling.

So we might go from

```
private void somethingCoupledToTheWorld(args...) {
    // Complicated things here
}
```

to

```
class DecoupledThing {
    public nowEasyToTest(args...) {
        // Complicated things here
    }
}

private DecoupledThing that = DecoupledThing()

private void somethingCoupledToTheWorld(args...) {
    that.nowEasyToTest(args)
}
```

The resulting designs tend to have more modules; especially (a) more modules that do one thing well (SRP), and (b) more modules that don't seem to do much themselves except to delegate work to other modules.

Another way of expressing the same idea: we adapt our designs so that the high risk code is located in modules that are easy to test.

Some good news: if you've got tests of A already, you can still use them.  They help to ensure that the behavior of the code doesn't change as you refactor your design toward a design that supports more focused testing.